# Ember.js - Loading additional .js-Files in some templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Im developing a ember.js based app.
On some "sites" (templates) I want to load a specific js-game, so I have to include extra tags like `<script src="game.js"></script>`. But since handlebar-templates are defined by `<script>`-Tags itself, its not possible to simply put my dependencies within a template directly.

How can I include js-files on some individual sites only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an possibility to solve that problem:

Like described in the handlebars.js-FAQ  [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/FAQ.md) (5.), I have to use some kind of a "Hack" to avoid parsing errors. Just need to add an empty command `{{!}}` into the word "script" like `<scr{{!}}ipt src=...>...</scr{{!}}ipt`.

That works for me.
Also, as kpdecker says [here](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/531), it is better to use precompiled templates than defining them inline.

Answer (score 0):

Including files in an Ember.js application is a bit more complex than in a regular website.

If you do **not** use [ember-cli](http://www.ember-cli.com/), then you could either include your all your JavaScript files directly in your `index.html` (one by one) or (and this is better) you could also bundle all your game JavaScript files into a single file (called `games.js` for instance) and include that single file in your `index.html`. You can bundle JavaScript files using tools such as [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [brunch](http://brunch.io/) or [broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli).

Now if you **do** use ember-cli (which I recommend), then you could simply list your files in your Brocfile.js (see documentation [here](http://www.ember-cli.com/#managing-dependencies)). Learning ember-cli might take a little bit of extra time but it will really help you in the future :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Pedro for that! But my problem is a little bit more complex: I cant include all my js files into the index.html at once. I have to decide between the current active template (path) and others (In fact Ive got more than one game which all uses their own implementations of the same functions). If I include all js at the same time (mainGame.js, level01.js, level02.js, ...) only the last level0*.js would be used (override the functions).

So there must be a way to modify the included <script>-Tags depending on the currently used template. Any Idea?

Comment: In Ember 2.x, Brocfile.js has become ember-cli-build.js

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert the necessary scripts from `didInsertElement` hook of the corresponding view. And, if so, in order to avoid duplicates, remove that scripts in `willDestroyElement` hook of the same view.

Comment: Well if I got it right, changing the template while navigation through the page (from "game/play" to "game/credits" for example) everything within the last template are removed from the rendered DOM already, so I have not do deal with removing <script>-Tags from the last template.

BUT(!):
Javascript-Files loaded in the browser as a resource once, will be kept into it and stay at life as long as the whole page will reloaded or changed. I dont know how to handle that!

Comment: If you insert script somewhere outside the template, it won't be removed on view's destroy. Regarding the resources problem, that's normal because Ember-based application is single-page one, and it can't be fixed with JS because of security restrictions.